# load pdf from url in android

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I have to display pdf file in webview using this link
https://col1.3yd.co:8087/api/getDoc?username=test&password=12345678&doc_id=dc_1

The problem is when i open this link in webview using online google docs viewer, then i am getting error "Whoops!! There was a problem displaying this image."

https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://col1.3yd.co:8087/api/getDoc?username=test&password=12345678&doc_id=dc_1

After trying too many methods from stackoverflower I am using this code to load pdf file.
The problem is each time file is downloading and its taking time. Is there any other way to display file in webview.

```
 private void downloadAndOpenPDF(){

 progressDialog = new DLProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.show();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(downloadFile(download_file_url));
            try {
                if(progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }
    }).start();

}

private File downloadFile(String dwnload_file_path) {
    File file = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(dwnload_file_path);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        // connect
        urlConnection.connect();
        // set the path where we want to save the file
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // create a new file, to save the downloaded file
        file = new File(SDCardRoot, dest_file_path);
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        // Stream used for reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        // this is the total size of the file which we are
        // downloading
        totalsize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        // create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;

        while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            per = ((float) downloadedSize / totalsize) * 100;
              }
        // close the output stream when complete //
        fileOutput.close();

    } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {

    } catch (final IOException e) {

    } catch (final Exception e) {

    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: You should use download manager to actually download the file

Comment: But i dont want to download the file. i just want to display in webview.

Comment: But you are downloading it!  If you want to display it in the WebView, then simply get the WebView instance and point it to the URL.

Comment: I have tried with webview.loadurl(url); but its not displaying pdf file in webview. and when i try any other pdf link then it is displaying in webview.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use WebView for displaying PDF?  Maybe you should look at a PDF display library instead.

Comment: Yeah. becaue i dont want to download the file each time .

Comment: I have also tried 
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
               webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}